# Java get multiple values from a class method

Tags: java

I am pretty new with Java OOP and I am trying to make a simple program that solves 2nd degree equations.

```
package sistemiequazioni;

public class sistemi {

    private double delta(double a, double b, double c) {
     return (b*b) - 4*a*c;
    }

    public double[] grado2(double a, double b, double c) {
     double Delta = delta(a,b,c);

     if (Delta > -1) {
       double x1 = (-b-Math.sqrt(Delta))/(2*a);
       double x2 = (-b+Math.sqrt(Delta))/(2*a);
       return new double[] { x1 , x2 };
     } else {
       return 0;
     }

    }
```

I have a package that contains 2 classes: this one which is called `sistemi` and another one called `form1` which has the main. In `form1` I use:

```
sistemi d = new sistemi();

//get the values of a,b,c from the jTextFields

double[] k = new double[2];
k = d.grado2(a, b, c);

jTextField1.setText(String.valueOf(k[1]) + " and " + k[2]);
```

It returns 2 values (x1 and x2) and I need to store them in that array called `k`. How could I do it?

As I have already said I am new with this new stuff. I have googled this and I found how to pass multiple values from a method, but not how to store them in a variable.

Comment: Class names should start with a capital letter. And indentation is up to you, but I've never seen people use 2 spaces in java. And, regarding your code: arrays are 0-indexed, so use `k[0]` and `k[1]`

Comment: Oh yes you're right, I have just noticed it. I was wont with Delphi.

Comment: Maybe not directly related to your question (as KEYSER already advised here), but you might find it useful looking here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/46293/quadratic-expression-calculator for some suggestions and tips of what can be done with regards to the quadratic equasion calculator.

Comment: @Phoenix please don't edit code in questions.

Comment: Class names should start with an uppercase letter, while variable names (like Delta) should start with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to create an array before calling the function, because function creates and returns one already:

```
double[] k = new double[2];
k = d.grado2(a, b, c);
/// into
double[] k = d.grado2(a, b, c);
```

Secondly, if you have to return 2 values, which have a meaning, return object of a class with 2 members. Or better yet, make a class which represents the equation and returns each results with a getter:

```
public class QuadraticEquation {
    private Double solution1;
    private Double solution2;
    public QuadraticEquation(double a, double b, double c) {
        // delta 0 has 1 solution, delta > 0 has 2 solution
        double delta = b * b - 4 * a * c;
        if (delta >= 0) {
            solution1 = (-b - Math.sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
            solution2 = (-b + Math.sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
        }
    }
    public boolean hasSolutions() {
        return solution1 != null || solution2 != null;
    }
    public Double getSolution1() {
        return solution1;
    }
    public Double getSolution2() {
        return solution2;
    }
}
```

I used Double type because it can have `null` value, which means no solution. Java will autobox it to double. As such you can write this code:

```
QuadraticEquation eq = new QuadraticEquation(1, 2, 1);
if (eq.hasSolutions()) {
    if (eq.getSolution1() == eq.getSolution2()) {
        System.out.println("Equation has solution " + eq.getSolution1();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Equation has solutions " + eq.getSolution1() + 
           " and " + eq.getSolution2());
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("Equation has no real solutions ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning just 0 as your return type is `double[]` you can do

```
else {

      return new double[] { 0 , 0 };

     }
```

Also as suggested in comments array start with index 0. So you need to use

```
jTextField1.setText(String.valueOf(k[0]) + " and " + k[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

### Current problem

You can't return 0, because 0 is not an array. What you can do is returning an array that contains only one element, but you have to carefully think about the meaning you give to your return value.

If you want your method to return an array containing the solutions, then so be it, but it will not always be of length 2. You have to deal with all the possible cases:

- if there are 2 solutions: `return new double[] { x1, x2 };`
- if there is only 1 solution: `return new double[] { x };`
- if there is no solution: `return new double[0];`

### Error in the logic

There is also an error in your code logic. Some `Delta` values are not dealt with properly:

- if `-1 < Delta < 0` then you have no solution (I assume you don't use complex numbers here)
- if `Delta == 0` then there is only one solution, which is `-b/(2*a)` (since it's a double solution, you might want to return an array containing it twice, so this case might be ok)

I think your test on Delta should therefore be:

```
if (Delta > 0) {
    // calculate 2 solutions x1 and x2
    return new double[] { x1, x2 };
} else if (Delta == 0) {
    // calculate 1 solution x
    return new double[] { x };
} else {
    return new double[0]; // no solution
}
```

Or if you want to take into account the fact that the single solution is twice solution:

```
if (Delta >= 0) {
    // calculate 2 solutions x1 and x2
    return new double[] { x1, x2 };
} else {
    return new double[0]; // no solution
}
```

### How to make a method store things in a variable

In your current version, this is what you do:

```
double[] k = new double[2]; // creates an array of double that contains 2 slots
k = d.grado2(a, b, c); // REPLACES it by whatever the method returned
```

`k` is just a variable pointing to the created array. If you affect it with something else (such as the method's return value) then it does not point to your former array anymore.

What you *could* do is passing `k` **as an argument of your method**, and your method would write in the slots of that array. However, this is not needed here. Moreover, you can't know in advance that there will be 2 solutions, unless you deal with complex numbers, but that's another story.

You should therefore replace the above 2 lines by:

```
double[] k = d.grado2(a, b, c);
```